# how to use different url structure in php?

Tags: php

how to use different url structure in php ?
I want to know to handle url like this
 
www.example.com/10/2011
instead of 
www.example.com/?m=10&y=2011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it will be better to do with server configuration - .htaccess (in Apache) or web.config (in IIS). Create rewrite rule from ^(\d+)/(\d+)$ to /?m=$1&y=$2. For example, in Apache it will look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\d+)$ /?m=$1&y=$2
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved through [apache's mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) mechanism. create a `.htaccess` file in your webroot with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) ?m=$1&y=$2 [NC]
```

similar mechanisms exist for other web servers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Rewrite(google it) engine in Apache or nginx.
Something like this exists in ISS too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not achieved by PHP, but by some other "component". E.g. the Apache web server has a module (the rewrite engine) that can rewrite the URL so that you can use URL like `www.example.com/10/2011` and it translates them into `www.example.com/?m=10&y=2011` so that in your PHP code you can use $_GET['m'] and get the month. [Rewrite engine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for Apache (for other webserver similar things may exist)

Answer (score 0):

One easy method is something like this:

In your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

What this does it redirects everyhting to index.php if its not a physical file or dir.

Then you configure your index.php to handle this request.

Example

www.example.com/10/2011

will become `$_GET['10/2011']`;
so you can use data in your script.

Comment: Obviously this is for apache. Other web servers may have different approaches